# AS3 - Display the same Sprite in button states

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to add a sprite to all the states of a button. I have something like (speudo code):

```
var button:SimpleButton= new SimpleButton();
var content:Sprite = new Sprite();
button.upState.addChild(content);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPress);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onRelease);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

private function onPress(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    //move content to downState
    button.downState.addChild(content);
}

private function onRelease(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    //move content to upState
    button.upState.addChild(content);
}

private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    //main action when clicking on the button
}
```

It's working, but the problem is that the content disappears for a frame when I press the button / release it. I guess it's due to the events not being fired at the same time.
How could I solve something like that?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact of using the single instance of **content** for all the 3 states. Try creating 3 distinct instances of it and just add them to all 3 states, you won't even need to handle the events this way.

Comment: Don't plain use simplebuttons, use a sprite with onClick set

Comment: I ended using Sprites in the end, it's easier to handle. Too bad the SimpleButton is such a pain to use. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @yvant Ok. then subscribe **upState**, **overState**, etc. to the ADDED_TO_STAGE event, and attach **content** to the event target.